# Can we restrict HTTP methods only to GET and POST using AWS WAF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I have hosted my application on AWS and I have implemented AWS WAF for security purposes. My current requirement is to allow only HTTP methods GET and POST using AWS WAF.

I've created and tested with 2 rules:

1. Allow-only-HTTP-GET
2. Allow-only-HTTP-POST

where each rule only allows the mentioned methods. But, as the WAF checks for all rules and therefore each rule mentioned above will block the other as per the implementation.

Is there a way to include both the cases in a single rule or add multiple statements in a single rule in WAF. Something like:

1. Allow-only-HTTP-GET-and-POST

Can we do that in a simple manner? Or do we need to think of other scenarios?

Comment: OR logic ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-or.html

Comment: Thanks Matt. That worked after using OR logic.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the "OR logic" by Matt in the comments, I have created a WAF rule that allows only GET and POST HTTP methods. I'm sharing the WAF Rule JSON for others' benefit.

```
{
  "Name": "Allow-only-HTTP-GET-and-POST",
  "Priority": 0,
  "Statement": {
    "AndStatement": {
      "Statements": [
        {
          "NotStatement": {
            "Statement": {
              "ByteMatchStatement": {
                "SearchString": "GET",
                "FieldToMatch": {
                  "Method": {}
                },
                "TextTransformations": [
                  {
                    "Priority": 1,
                    "Type": "NONE"
                  }
                ],
                "PositionalConstraint": "EXACTLY"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "NotStatement": {
            "Statement": {
              "ByteMatchStatement": {
                "SearchString": "POST",
                "FieldToMatch": {
                  "Method": {}
                },
                "TextTransformations": [
                  {
                    "Priority": 0,
                    "Type": "NONE"
                  }
                ],
                "PositionalConstraint": "EXACTLY"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Action": {
    "Block": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "Allow-only-HTTP-GET-and-POST"
  }
}
```